# python csv reader selecting specific rows

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose we have a text file as given below:

```
sfgsdgfs >sfsf > "assfgs.jpg">sggw.sgw
sgsdfghsg>sdgsgsgsg[]
werw>"erqwer.jpg">egfwrewrw
```

How to extract the rows that contain .jpg? What is wrong with the following code?

```
import csv
data = csv.reader (open ('outfile.txt', 'r'), delimiter = '"')
for row in data:
    if '.jpg' in row:
        print (row)
```

Comment: I think the delimiter should be `>`. Or you don't have to use `csv`.@guava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a list of column data items, you should iterate over it too:

```
import csv

data = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'r'), delimiter='"')
for row in data:
    for item in row:
        if '.jpg' in item:
            print(item)
```

prints:

```
assfgs.jpg
erqwer.jpg
```

Comment: thank you very much, i will accept your answer after 8 minutes